# Stan_glmer object assignment error

Tags: r, stan

After waiting a week for three MC chains to run, the object was not
saved, giving the error "Error: is.atomic(x) is not TRUE".  I have run
this code or variants thereof many times, so it is probably not my
syntax, but possibly something about the object size or an internal
stan_glmer error?  Log is below and thank you for any help (also
advice on how to save intermediate chains would be useful!)

```
stan.T.mod <- stan_glmer(form2, iter=5000, warmup=5000, thin=1, 
  family = binomial(link = "logit"), prior = student_t(location=0, df = 1, scale = 2.5), 
  prior_intercept = student_t(location=0, df = 1, scale=2.5),
  prior_covariance = decov(shape = 10, scale = 1), 
  chains = 3, seed = 0305991, data=Tbinary.dt)
```

> SAMPLING FOR MODEL 'bernoulli' NOW (CHAIN 1).
>
> Chain 1, Iteration:    1 / 5000 [  0%]  (Warmup) Chain 1, Iteration: 
>   500 / 5000 [ 10%]  (Warmup) Chain 1, Iteration: 1000 / 5000 [ 20%] 
>   (Warmup) Chain 1, Iteration: 1500 / 5000 [ 30%]  (Warmup) Chain 1,
>   Iteration: 2000 / 5000 [ 40%]  (Warmup) Chain 1, Iteration: 2500 /
>   5000 [ 50%]  (Warmup) Chain 1, Iteration: 3000 / 5000 [ 60%]  (Warmup)
>   Chain 1, Iteration: 3500 / 5000 [ 70%]  (Warmup) Chain 1, Iteration:
>   4000 / 5000 [ 80%]  (Warmup) Chain 1, Iteration: 4500 / 5000 [ 90%] 
>   (Warmup) Chain 1, Iteration: 5000 / 5000 [100%]  (Warmup) Elapsed
>   Time: 394305 seconds (Warm-up)
>                  0 seconds (Sampling)
>                  394305 seconds (Total)
>
> SAMPLING FOR MODEL 'bernoulli' NOW (CHAIN 2).
>
> Chain 2, Iteration:    1 / 5000 [  0%]  (Warmup) Chain 2, Iteration: 
>   500 / 5000 [ 10%]  (Warmup) Chain 2, Iteration: 1000 / 5000 [ 20%] 
>   (Warmup) Chain 2, Iteration: 1500 / 5000 [ 30%]  (Warmup) Chain 2,
>   Iteration: 2000 / 5000 [ 40%]  (Warmup) Chain 2, Iteration: 2500 /
>   5000 [ 50%]  (Warmup) Chain 2, Iteration: 3000 / 5000 [ 60%]  (Warmup)
>   Chain 2, Iteration: 3500 / 5000 [ 70%]  (Warmup) Chain 2, Iteration:
>   4000 / 5000 [ 80%]  (Warmup) Chain 2, Iteration: 4500 / 5000 [ 90%] 
>   (Warmup) Chain 2, Iteration: 5000 / 5000 [100%]  (Warmup) Elapsed
>   Time: 434251 seconds (Warm-up)
>                  0 seconds (Sampling)
>                  434251 seconds (Total)
>
> SAMPLING FOR MODEL 'bernoulli' NOW (CHAIN 3).
>
> Chain 3, Iteration:    1 / 5000 [  0%]  (Warmup) Chain 3, Iteration: 
>   500 / 5000 [ 10%]  (Warmup) Chain 3, Iteration: 1000 / 5000 [ 20%] 
>   (Warmup) Chain 3, Iteration: 1500 / 5000 [ 30%]  (Warmup) Chain 3,
>   Iteration: 2000 / 5000 [ 40%]  (Warmup) Chain 3, Iteration: 2500 /
>   5000 [ 50%]  (Warmup) Chain 3, Iteration: 3000 / 5000 [ 60%]  (Warmup)
>   Chain 3, Iteration: 3500 / 5000 [ 70%]  (Warmup) Chain 3, Iteration:
>   4000 / 5000 [ 80%]  (Warmup) Chain 3, Iteration: 4500 / 5000 [ 90%] 
>   (Warmup) Chain 3, Iteration: 5000 / 5000 [100%]  (Warmup) Elapsed
>   Time: 345070 seconds (Warm-up)
>                  0 seconds (Sampling)
>                  345070 seconds (Total)
>
> Error: is.atomic(x) is not TRUE

```
save(stan.T.mod, file=paste0(outpath, "stan.GCMfixedmods"));
```

> Error in save(stan.T.mod, file = paste0(outpath, "stan.GCMfixedmods")) :
>   object ‘stan.T.mod’ not found
>
> > stan.T.mod Error: object 'stan.T.mod' not found

Comment: I think the problem is that `iter=5000, warmup=5000` results it zero iterations being saved. You really shouldn't need to change the defaults of `iter = 2000` and `warmup` being half of that.

Comment: OMG, that is so incredibly funny (and stupid)!  Thanks - i'm glad there is an easy answer (and another week).

Comment: Had the same issue in `brms` package which runs Stan internally. I guess different MCMC packages are inconsistent in terms of whether `iter` means all iterations past warmup/burn-in, or the total number of iterations including warmup.